# Android Change System Settings permission is not accessible

Tags: java, android, permissions

The code below should allow access (permission / disable) to Change System Setting as below.
But it doesn't work - the switch can't be turned to on.
My android version is 9.
What's wrong?

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean enabled = true;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !android.provider.Settings.System.canWrite(MainActivity.this)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                Settings.System.putInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.screenrotation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS "/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do not forget to add detail such as how the code fails / error description and android version.

Answer (score 5):

Resolved by adding this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add this line on your manifest file it's will work 100%**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

**More info**
[Follow my youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/Rajmeetamil)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" /> it's will work 100% just try it